# i want hide or disable right click option in elementor editor for the editor user role

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

i want hide or disable right click option in elementor editor for the editor user role. there is no plugin to do it

Actually I need editor user role to be able to edit only, not change

I asked chatGPT to write a code to solve this problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work

```
function disable_elementor_right_click() {
    if (current_user_can('editor')) {
        ?>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'disable_elementor_right_click');
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem but elementor already provides a role manager.
Here you can limit the user so that he can only customize the content but ist not able to remove/move/change the elements themselves.
You can find the role manager in the backend under: Elementor > Role Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try a slightly different approach by using jQuery to achieve the same result?

This code snippet checks if the current user role is "editor" and then prevents the right-click context menu. Remember to add this code to your theme's JavaScript file or your custom script, and make sure jQuery is properly enqueued. Always be cautious when modifying core behavior, as it might affect the overall user experience.

```
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ('editor' === wp.data.select('core').getCurrentUser().roles[0]) {
            $(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```